# Can't modify a property of an object in an array after using the filter method

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays of objects (the same): 1 (artificesToAdd[]) which can contain 0 or more objects and the 2nd (newFilter[]) which can also contain 0 to a couple of objects, based on a search performed by a user.

The goal is that for each object contained in the artificesToAdd[] array, I check if this object also exists in the newFilter[] array.
If so, I need to update the 'qtyToAdd' property to indicate the quantity that is initially in my first array.

Unfortunately I get this error :

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property qtyToAdd, object is not extensible'
```

My understanding is that this array can't be modified because it's in reference but I'm not sure about this and I don't know how to resolve it?
Should I create another array and push items needed inside?

The error occur on this particular line:  newFilter[artIndex].qtyToAdd = item.qty;

```
    const handleFilter = (event: any) => {
    const searchWord: string = event.target.value;
    const newFilter = artifices.filter((value) => {
        return value.codeGF.toUpperCase().includes(searchWord.toUpperCase());
    });
    // Now let's add ART who had a qty
    if (artificesToAdd.length > 0) {
        let artIndex: number;

        artificesToAdd.forEach(function (item) {
            artIndex = newFilter.findIndex((i) => i.id === item.id);
            if (artIndex === -1 || artIndex === undefined) return;
            console.log(newFilter[artIndex]);
            newFilter[artIndex].qtyToAdd = item.qty;
        });
    }
    setFilteredArtifices(newFilter);
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible

Answer (score 0):

This might be a reach, but try changing this:  "const newFilter ="
to this:  "let newFilter="

Comment: It doesnt change, I've already tried this.